# Odoo 10 create project from sales order

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm designing a button to select/create a new project from sales order.

This is my module:

```
@api.multi
def action_create_project_project(self):
    view_id = self.env.ref('project.project_project_view_form_simplified').id
    context = self._context.copy()
    return {
        'name': 'Create project',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'views' : [(view_id, 'form')],
        'res_model': 'project.project',
        'view_id': view_id,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        # 'res_id': self.id,
        'target': 'new',
        'context': context,
    }
```

And the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        <record id="view_order_form_inherit_sale_timesheet" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Sale Order create project</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>
                    <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_shipping_id']" position="after">
                        <field name="project_project_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <label for="action_create_project_project" string="Create project" invisible="[('project_project_id', '!=', False)]"/>
                        <button type="object"
                            name="action_create_project_project"
                            class="fa fa-external-link btn btn-default o_external_button"
                            string="New project"
                            groups="base.group_user"
                            attrs="{'invisible': [('project_project_id', '!=', False)]}">
                        </button>
                    </xpath>
                </data>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

But what I would really want is to select existing project or create a new one, and when the project is selected I need to access to the project, obtain `analytic_account_id` and fill Sale Order with this information.

Any help please?

Maybe I could modify `project_project_id` definition in order to let it be writeable on sale order draft (created by `sale_timesheet` with readonly flag to true) but I don't know can I override a field from an addon (would like to keep core intact)...

Original:

```
project_project_id = fields.Many2one('project.project',
    compute='_compute_project_project_id',
    string='Project associated to this sale',
    )
```

Desired:

```
project_project_id = fields.Many2one('project.project',
    'Project associated to this sale',
    compute='_compute_project_project_id',
    readonly=True,
    states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},
    copy=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override and existing field, just add the attributes that you need, something like this:

```
project_project_id = fields.Many2one(
    readonly=True,
    states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},
    copy=False)
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.